# Volume Shadow Copy Monitoring Script

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and am trying to write a Powershell script that I can use to monitor the status of VSS on our servers using an RMM tool. What I have so far is:

```
# List all Volumes
$Volumes = gwmi Win32_Volume -Property SystemName,DriveLetter,DeviceID,Capacity,FreeSpace -Filter "DriveType=3" |
Select SystemName,@{n="DriveLetter";e={$_.DriveLetter.ToUpper()}},DeviceID,@{n="CapacityGB";e={([math]::Round([int64]($_.Capacity)/1GB,2))}},@{n="FreeSpaceGB";e={([math]::Round([int64]($_.FreeSpace)/1GB,2))}} | Sort DriveLetter

# get all shadow storage volumes
$ShadowStorage = gwmi Win32_ShadowStorage -Property AllocatedSpace,DiffVolume,MaxSpace,UsedSpace,Volume |
Select @{n="Volume";e={$_.Volume.Replace("\\","\").Replace("Win32_Volume.DeviceID=","").Replace("`"","")}},
                @{n="DiffVolume";e={$_.DiffVolume.Replace("\\","\").Replace("Win32_Volume.DeviceID=","").Replace("`"","")}},
                @{n="AllocatedSpaceGB";e={([math]::Round([int64]($_.AllocatedSpace)/1GB,2))}},
                @{n="MaxSpaceGB";e={([math]::Round([int64]($_.MaxSpace)/1GB,2))}},
                @{n="UsedSpaceGB";e={([math]::Round([int64]($_.UsedSpace)/1GB,2))}}

# list all shadow coppies
$ShadowCopies = gwmi Win32_ShadowCopy -Property VolumeName,InstallDate,Count |
                Select VolumeName,InstallDate,Count,
                @{n="CreationDate";e={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.InstallDate)}}

# format and output stats
$Shares = gwmi win32_share -Property Name,Path | Select Name,@{n="Path";e={$_.Path.ToUpper()}}
            If($Volumes)
            {
                $Output = @()
                ForEach($Volume in $Volumes)
                {
                    $VolumeShares = $VolumeShadowStorage = $DiffVolume = $VolumeShadowCopies = $Null
                    If($Volume.DriveLetter -ne $Null){[array]$VolumeShares = $Shares | ?{$_.Path.StartsWith($Volume.DriveLetter)}}
                    $VolumeShadowStorage = $ShadowStorage | ?{$_.Volume -eq $Volume.DeviceID}
                    If($VolumeShadowStorage){$DiffVolume = $Volumes | ?{$_.DeviceID -eq $VolumeShadowStorage.DiffVolume}}
                    $VolumeShadowCopies = $ShadowCopies | ?{$_.VolumeName -eq $Volume.DeviceID} | Sort InstallDate
                    $Object = New-Object psobject
                    $Object | Add-Member NoteProperty SystemName $Volume.SystemName -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty DriveLetter $Volume.DriveLetter -PassThru |
                        Add-Member NoteProperty CapacityGB $Volume.CapacityGB -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty FreeSpaceGB $Volume.FreeSpaceGB -PassThru |
                        Add-Member NoteProperty ShareCount "" -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty Shares "" -PassThru |
                        Add-Member NoteProperty ShadowAllocatedSpaceGB "" -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty ShadowUsedSpaceGB "" -PassThru |
                        Add-Member NoteProperty ShadowMaxSpaceGB "" -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty DiffVolumeDriveLetter "" -PassThru |
                        Add-Member NoteProperty DiffVolumeCapacityGB "" -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty DiffVolumeFreeSpaceGB "" -PassThru |
                        Add-Member NoteProperty ShadowCopyCount "" -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty OldestShadowCopy "" -PassThru |
                        Add-Member NoteProperty LatestShadowCopy "" -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty ShadowAverageSizeGB "" -PassThru | Add-Member NoteProperty ShadowAverageSizeMB ""
    If($VolumeShares)
                    {   $Object.ShareCount = $VolumeShares.Count
                        If($VolumeShares.Count -eq 1){$Object.Shares = $VolumeShares[0].Name}
                        Else{$Object.Shares = [string]::join(", ", ($VolumeShares | Select Name)).Replace("@{Name=", "").Replace("}", "")}
                    }
                    If($VolumeShadowStorage)
                    {   $Object.ShadowAllocatedSpaceGB = $VolumeShadowStorage.AllocatedSpaceGB
                        $Object.ShadowUsedSpaceGB = $VolumeShadowStorage.UsedSpaceGB
                        $Object.ShadowMaxSpaceGB = $VolumeShadowStorage.MaxSpaceGB
                        If($DiffVolume)
                        {   $Object.DiffVolumeDriveLetter = $DiffVolume.DriveLetter
                            $Object.DiffVolumeCapacityGB = $DiffVolume.CapacityGB
                            $Object.DiffVolumeFreeSpaceGB = $DiffVolume.FreeSpaceGB
                        }
                    }
                    If($VolumeShadowCopies)
                    {   $Object.ShadowCopyCount = (($VolumeShadowCopies | Measure-Object -Property Count -Sum).Sum)
                        $Object.OldestShadowCopy = (($VolumeShadowCopies | Select -First 1).CreationDate)
                        $Object.LatestShadowCopy = (($VolumeShadowCopies | Select -Last 1).CreationDate)
                        If($VolumeShadowStorage.UsedSpaceGB -gt 0 -And $Object.ShadowCopyCount -gt 0)
                        {   $Object.ShadowAverageSizeGB = ([math]::Round($VolumeShadowStorage.UsedSpaceGB/$Object.ShadowCopyCount,2))
                            $Object.ShadowAverageSizeMB = ([math]::Round(($VolumeShadowStorage.UsedSpaceGB*1KB)/$Object.ShadowCopyCount,2))
                        }

                        }
                    }
                    If($VolumeShadowStorage -Or $ShowAllVolumes){$Output += $Object}
                }
                $Output
```

This will output a block of information like this:

```
SystemName             : server
DriveLetter            : F:
CapacityGB             : 1850
FreeSpaceGB            : 676.75
ShareCount             : 17
Shares                 : List of shares
ShadowAllocatedSpaceGB : 71.41
ShadowUsedSpaceGB      : 62.3
ShadowMaxSpaceGB       : 292.97
DiffVolumeDriveLetter  : F:
DiffVolumeCapacityGB   : 1850
DiffVolumeFreeSpaceGB  : 676.75
ShadowCopyCount        : 961
OldestShadowCopy       : 4/25/2020 8:39:29 AM
LatestShadowCopy       : 7/8/2020 9:17:56 AM
ShadowAverageSizeGB    : 0.06
ShadowAverageSizeMB    : 66.38
```

What I need to do so this will work with our RMM tools is break out each line of this output into their own variables so the RMM tool can read each one. For context this is the script we use now, it works but it really only outputs the basics:

```
 $plaintext=vssadmin list writers
    $vsswriters=@()
    foreach ($line in $plaintext) {
        switch -regex ($line) {
            ("^Writer name:") {
                $vsswriters+=$Obj
                Remove-Variable -name Obj -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 
                $Obj=New-Object System.Object
                $writername=($line -split ": ")[1] -replace "'",""
                $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "WriterName" -value $writername -Force
                Remove-Variable -Name writername -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                break;
            }
            ("^   ") {
                $attrname=($line -split ": ")[0] -Replace "   ",""
                $attrval=($line -split ": ")[1] -replace "'",""
                $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $attrname -value $attrval -Force
                Remove-Variable -Name attrname,attrval -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                break;
            }
            default {
                # Skip line as not required.
            }
        }
    }
 
    #$vsswriters  |ft
   
    $errorcount =0
    $notstablecount = 0
    $VSSinerror = "No VSS Writers Reporting Errors"
    $VSSnotstable = "No VSS Writers Reporting Unstable Status"
 
 
    foreach ($vsswriter in $vsswriters)
    {
       if($vsswriter.'Last error' -ne "No error" -and $vsswriter.WriterName -ne "" -and $vsswriter.WriterName -ne $null)
       {
            $errorcount = $errorcount +1
            if($VSSinerror -eq "No VSS Writers Reporting Errors")
            {
                $VSSinerror=$vsswriter.WriterName
            }
            else
            {
                $VSSinerror=$VSSinerror + ", " + $vsswriter.WriterName
            }
       }
       if($vsswriter.State -ne "[1] Stable"  -and $vsswriter.WriterName -ne ""  -and $vsswriter.WriterName -ne $null)
       {
            $notstablecount = $notstablecount +1
            if($VSSnotstable -eq "No VSS Writers Reporting Unstable Status")
            {
                $VSSnotstable=$vsswriter.WriterName
            }
            else
            {
                $VSSnotstable=$VSSnotstable + ", " + $vsswriter.WriterName
            }
       }
    }
 
 
 
 
 
 
 $outscvsserrors = $errorcount
 $outscvssinerrors = $VSSinerror
 $outscvssnotstablect = $notstablecount
 $outscvssnotstable = $VSSnotstable
 $outsctotalvss=$vsswriters.Count
 
 $outscvsserrors
 $outscvssinerrors
 $outscvssnotstablect
 $outscvssnotstable
 $outsctotalvss
```

What I have to do is feed this Powershell into a scripting tool that will allow me to map outputs to be monitored. [Here is what that looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNxvt.png) This is then read by our RMM tool [like like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFgri.png) Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to solve this problem I apologize if this is too broad of a question.

Comment: The first block do not output what you think it does. What you show is the textual represntation but behind the scene, it is a list of object. Is the second part a separate script ? If so, you might want to do `$Output | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content -Path 'SomeFile'` and import the csv back into an object for the second script using the opposite operation `$Output = Get-Content -Path 'SomeFilePath' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Csv`. If this is the same script though, you can pass directly to enumerating the objects individually through `Foreach ($Item in $Output) {#SecondScriptStuff}`

Comment: When you work with a singular object, you won't have to do all that parsing stuff. You'l lbe able to just do `$item.ThePropertyName` in your foreach to get the value of the object and do what you need, then in the end convert it to json,csv or whatever format the RMM tools will accept as input.

Comment: Yes the second part is a separate script its what is currently being used and was given as an example of what works now in our RMM tool. Once I have the first script working how I want we will not use it. I can't output to file though because the script runs in an odd way from the RMM tool it will not be able to save the csv.

Comment: What you suggest is exactly what I need to do though I just need the output to be confined to the the script just like how it is in the second script in the OP.

Comment: I see what you're saying the block after # format and output stats is really all I need the first few sections of the script are not needed. I guess I just need to break this section down into separate outputs?